# Create vector of integers intervals to remove multiple rows from data frame in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, vector, bioinformatics

I did a bioinformatic analysis which came out with a really bad formated results sheet with up to 60 000 rows. I need to remove a lot of results which don´t interest me.

Has example here is the first 20 rows of the data frame after text file import in R (the data frame has then only one column) :

```
Df <- structure(list(V1 = c(" QUERY: AT1G10657|AT1G10657.3;AT1G10657.2;AT1G10657.1;AT1G10657.4", 
" TFBS AC: RSP00038//OS: tomato (Lycopersicon esculentum), Lycopersicon esculentum /GENE: LAT52; LAT56;/TFBS: 52/56 box /BF: GT-1 related transcription factors", 
"     792  TGTGGTTATATt      781 (Mism.= 1)", " TFBS AC: RSP00621//OS: tomato (Lycopersicon esculentum), Lycopersicon esculentum /GENE: rbcS2/TFBS: C-rich Q /BF: unknown nuclear factor", 
"     716  CCtCTCCTC      724 (Mism.= 1)", " TFBS AC: RSP00654//OS: spinach (Spinacia oleracea) /GENE: PetH/TFBS: CT-B /BF: unknown nuclear factor", 
"     322  CACCCAaTTC      331 (Mism.= 1)", " TFBS AC: RSP00863//OS: arabidopsis (Arabidopsis thaliana) /GENE: STK/TFBS: GA-4 /BF: BPC1", 
"     991  AGAGAGGAA      999 (Mism.= 0)", " TFBS AC: RSP01275//OS: parsley (Petroselinum crispum) /GENE: PcACO-IV/TFBS: ACE 2 /BF: 2 unknown noncooperative nuclear factors", 
"     212  TtCACGTCAT      221 (Mism.= 1)", " TFBS AC: RSP01304//OS: tomato (Lycopersicon esculentum) /GENE: A1 EF-1alpha/TFBS: Telo box /BF: unknown nuclear factor", 
"     553  aGAACCCTAA      562 (Mism.= 1)", " TFBS AC: RSP01661//OS: Arabidopsis (Arabidopsis thaliana) /GENE: CKX5/6 (At1g75450)/TFBS: C/G-box /BF: HY5", 
"     222  TATGACGTGAaa      211 (Mism.= 2)", " TFBS AC: RSP02010//OS: Arabidopsis (Arabidopsis thaliana) /GENE: MYB2/TFBS: W-box 6 /BF: WRKY40", 
"      78  aCCAGTCACTtT       89 (Mism.= 2)", " TFBS AC: RSP02326//OS: Arabidopsis (Arabidopsis thaliana) /GENE: BiP2/TFBS: TL1 /BF: TBF1", 
"     452  GAAGAAGAA      460 (Mism.= 0)", "     950  GAAGAAGAA      958 (Mism.= 0)"
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to keep only the "QUERY" lines and the "TFBS" from the plant "Arabidopsis" and the sequence(s) below each lines mentioning "Arabidopsis" and so remove all the data from other plants (here "tomato", "parsley" or "spinach").

So for now what I did was to use regular expression to index the rows containing the info I want or not.

```
Index_Query <- which(grepl("QUERY", Df$V1))
Index_Df_arabi <- which(grepl("arabidopsis|Arabidopsis", Df$V1))
Index_Df_other <- which(grepl("tomato|spinach|parsley", Df$V1))

> Index_Query
[1] 1

> Index_Df_arabi
[1]  8 14 16 18

> Index_Df_other
[1]  2  4  6 10 12
```

And so I would like to keep the row(s) "QUERY" and to remove all the rows in the interval between rows from **Index_Df_other** (including it) to the next from **Index_Df_arabi** (excluding it) and keep the rows from **Index_Df_arabi** (including  it) to the next from **Index_Df_other** (excluding it).

So in that case get a data frame like that

```
> Df[c(1,8:9,14:20),]
 [1]  QUERY: AT1G10657|AT1G10657.3;AT1G10657.2;AT1G10657.1;AT1G10657.4                                          
 [2]  TFBS AC: RSP00863//OS: arabidopsis (Arabidopsis thaliana) /GENE: STK/TFBS: GA-4 /BF: BPC1                 
 [3]      991  AGAGAGGAA      999 (Mism.= 0)                                                                    
 [4]  TFBS AC: RSP01661//OS: Arabidopsis (Arabidopsis thaliana) /GENE: CKX5/6 (At1g75450)/TFBS: C/G-box /BF: HY5
 [5]      222  TATGACGTGAaa      211 (Mism.= 2)                                                                 
 [6]  TFBS AC: RSP02010//OS: Arabidopsis (Arabidopsis thaliana) /GENE: MYB2/TFBS: W-box 6 /BF: WRKY40           
 [7]       78  aCCAGTCACTtT       89 (Mism.= 2)                                                                 
 [8]  TFBS AC: RSP02326//OS: Arabidopsis (Arabidopsis thaliana) /GENE: BiP2/TFBS: TL1 /BF: TBF1                 
 [9]      452  GAAGAAGAA      460 (Mism.= 0)                                                                    
[10]      950  GAAGAAGAA      958 (Mism.= 0)
```

I tried to directly use the Index through my data frame doing some loops but I am not really familiar with that and it was unsuccessful

An idea I have would be to create a vector of intervals or if impossible create a vector containing all the rows numbers I want to remove/keep

I tried that also unsuccessfully

```
for(a in 1:length(Index_Df_arabi))for(b in 1:length(Index_Df_other)){
if(Index_Df_other[b] < Index_Df_arabi[a] ){IndexAll <- Index_Df_other[b]:Index_Df_arabi[a]}
else{IndexAll <- Index_Df_arabi[a]:Index_Df_other[b]}

}

> IndexAll
[1] 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
```

I suppose that my loop is not functional because the vector **IndexAll** isn't in the loop but I have no clue how to implement it into.

If you have any idea about how I could manage to solve my problem without curating manually my data I would be really thankful.

I hope everything is clear enough

Looking forward to your reply

Comment: Things would be more accessible if your date were reproducible. You can make it reproducible with `dput()` or similar.

Comment: What is your ideal output, as well? E.g., what values do you want to remove (or keep) in your example?

Comment: I made it reproducible thanks for the advice. My ideal output would be what I did manually in the example (3rd code panel) with only left the query rows, the rows with arabidopsis and all the information about the binding sites ("TFBS AC:" rows) and the motifs sequences associated. Then I could manage to reorganize the data with `str_split_fixed()` notably in order to go further in my analysis.